# Ajax Async and Cyclic PHP request from JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Dumb question. I have two pages, "**Index.html**" and "**func.php**" in the same directory.
I'm trying to call the PHP page every 2 seconds, get it's ECHO and display it on a **paragraph** element.
No error, but the **paragraph** text simply won't change (and stay 0), here's the code:

**Index.html**

```
<html>
<body>

    <?php
        int cont = 0;
    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        req()
        { 
            $.ajax({url: "func.php"}, success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = data;
            });
            setInterval(req(), 2000);
        };

        $('document').ready(function(){
            setInterval(req(), 2000);
        });

    </script>

    <p id="p1">0</p>
</body>
```

**func.php**

```
<?php
    cont++;
    echo cont;
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: Your php code is broken. Variables start with `$`. You are never initializing the variable `$cont` anywhere too but try to increment it. *EDIT*: I see you do `int cont = 0;` on the top  in index.html but that will never work, learn the basics of php.

Comment: Every time you'll do your ajax call, the php script is initialised and your variable will have the same value. you might need to work with sessions.

Comment: @Xatenev yes sorry, i'm a beginner with PHP but that's just an oversight... I'm working with a lot different programming languages these days... however changing it in '$cont = 0;' didn't fix it.

Comment: @user2959923 Of course it didn't. Thats why I said learn the basics of php, and that includes the basics of the HTTP Request & Response Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the PHP syntax issues mentioned in the first comment above addressed, there are also issues with the javascript: the `}` after `func.php` is misplaced and needs and needs to be placed at the end of the ajax callback function instead. There is no need to have a `setInterval()` in the `req()` function because that is catered for when the function is called. There is also a missing `function` before the definition of the `req()` function.

To achieve the purpose, you would need to use PHP sessions, as mentioned in the second comment. Actually you do not need the PHP code in the index.html file. Here is a possible solution:

**index.html:**

```
<html>
<body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>

      function  req()
        { 
            $.ajax({url: "func.php", success: function(data) {
                document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = data;
            }});

        };

        $('document').ready(function(){
            setInterval(function(){req();}, 2000);
        });

    </script>

    <p id="p1">0</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**func.php:**

```
<?php session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['cont'])){
   $_SESSION['cont'] = 0;}
    else
    {$_SESSION['cont'] += 1; }

    echo $_SESSION['cont'];

?>
```